# Frequently Sending SDF Batches to CloudSearch

Tags: search, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to decide how frequently I should send changes in my db to CloudSearch. I can send the changes every minute, making search almost realtime, but is there a catch that I should consider?

Besides cost, are there any other reasons not to send sdf this frequently?

Answer (score 0):

It should be based on the application you are working on. for example one of my app was live cricket score cloud service, in which i call service every 5 second, and another was a hotel management system, which has dynamic price update on the basis room occupied, in that the cloud service(for updating DB) was called every 24 hrs.